# DDD: Where to put persistence logic, and when to use ORM mapping

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, dao

We are taking a long, hard look at our (Java) web application patterns. In the past, we've suffered from an overly anaemic object model and overly procedural separation between controllers, services and DAOs, with simple value objects (basically just bags of data) travelling between them. We've used declarative (XML) managed ORM (Hibernate) for persistence. All entity management has taken place in DAOs.

In trying to move to a richer domain model, we find ourselves struggling with how best to design the persistence layer. I've spent a lot of time reading and thinking about Domain Driven Design patterns. However, I'd like some advice.

First, the things I'm more confident about:

- We'll have "thin" controllers at the front that deal only with HTTP and HTML - processing forms, validation, UI logic.
- We'll have a layer of stateless business logic services that implements common algorithms or logic, unaware of the UI, but very much aware of (and delegating to) the domain model.
- We'll have a richer domain model which contains state, relationships, and logic inherent to the objects in that domain model.

The question comes around persistence. Previously, our services would be injected (via Spring) with DAOs, and would use DAO methods like find() and save() to perform persistence. However, a richer domain model would seem to imply that objects should know how to save and delete themselves, and perhaps that higher level services should know how to locate (query for) domain objects.

Here, a few questions and uncertainties arise:

- Do we want to inject DAOs into domain objects, so that they can do "this.someDao.save(this)" in a save() method? This is a little awkward since domain objects are not singletons, so we'll need factories or post-construction setting of DAOs. When loading entities from a database, this gets messy. I know Spring AOP can be used for this, but I couldn't get it to work (using Play! framework, another line of experimentation) and it seems quite messy and magical.
- Do we instead keep DAOs (repositories?) completely separate, on par with stateless  business logic services? This can make some sense, but it means that if "save" or "delete" are inherent operations of a domain object, the domain object can't express those.
- Do we just dispense with DAOs entirely and use JPA to let entities manage themselves.

Herein lies the next subtlety: It's quite convenient to map entities using JPA. The Play! framework gives us a nice entity base class, too, with operations like save() and delete(). However, this means that our domain model entities are quite closely tied to the database structure, and we are passing objects around with a large amount of persistence logic, perhaps all the way up to the view layer. If nothing else, this will make the domain model less re-usable in other contexts.

If we want to avoid this, then we'd need some kind of mapping DAO - either using simple JDBC (or at least Spring's JdbcTemplate), or using a parallel hierarchy of database entities and "business" entities, with DAOs forever copying information from one hierarchy to another.

What is the appropriate design choice here?

Martin

Comment: According to domain driven design - domain objects should be persistence ignorant.

Answer (score 3):

Your questions and doubts ring an interesting alarm here, I think you went a bit too far in your interpretation of a "rich domain model". Richness doesn't go as far as implying that persistence logic must be handled by the domain objects, in other words, no, they shouldn't know how to save and delete themselves (at least not explicitely, though Hibernate actually adds some persistence logic transparently). This is often referred to as persistence ignorance.

I suggest that you keep the existing DAO injection system (a nice thing to have for unit testing) and leave the persistence layer as is while trying to move some business logic to your entities *where it's fit*. A good starting point to do that is to identify Aggregates and establish your Aggregate Roots. They'll often contain more business logic than the other entities.

However, this is not to say domain objects should contain *all* logic (especially not logic needed by many other objects across the application, which often belongs in Services).

Comment: Well, fair point. But look at the last part of my question: Something like Hibernate/JPA makes it much easier to deal with persistence. However, if we do this on the domain model, then it has this logic built in. If we don't, then we'll either need to forgo ORM altogether, or have a parallel hierarchy of "mapped" objects and "domain" objects and data mappers between them.

Comment: Using JPA doesn't mean the domain objects should persist themselves -only contain descriptions of how to map themselves to database tables, and in this regard JPA is less persistence ignorant compared to pure Hibernate.

Comment: So I don't recommend injecting DAOs into domain objects.
On JPA and DDD you might find these 2 blog posts interesting : 
http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2007/10/domain-modeling-with-jpa-gotchas-part-4.html
http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2007/10//domain-modeling-what-exactly-is-rich.html

I wouldn't go the "parallel hierarchy" way either since it introduces uneeded complexity compared to just POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Java expert, but I use NHibernate in my .NET code so my experience should be directly translatable to the Java world.

When using ORM (like Hibernate you mentioned) to build Domain-Driven Design application, one of good (I won't say best) practices is to create so-called application services between the UI and the Domain. They are similar to stateless business objects you mentioned, but should contain almost no logic. They should look like this:

```
public void SayHello(int id, String helloString)
{
    SomeDomainObject target = domainObjectRepository.findById(id); //This uses Hibernate to load the object.

    target.sayHello(helloString); //There is a single domain object method invocation per application service method.

    domainObjectRepository.Save(target); //This one is optional. Hibernate should already know that this object needs saving because it tracks changes.
}
```

Any changes to objects contained by DomainObject (also adding objects to collections) will be handled by Hibernate.

You will also need some kind of AOP to intercept application service method invocations and create Hibernate's session before the method executes and save changes after method finishes with no exceptions.

There is a really good sample how to do DDD in Java [here](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/). It is based on the sample problem from Eric Evans' ['Blue Book'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). The application logic class sample code is [here](http://dddsample.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dddsample/branches/1_1_x/dddsample/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/application/impl/BookingServiceImpl.java?revision=436&view=markup).